# How can you handle trailing slashes in next.js routes?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to set up a next.js app, but I'm having trouble handling routes with a trailing slash. So, for example, if I have a pages structure like this:

```
pages
 - index.js
 - blog
   - index.js
   - [slug].js
```

then going to `/` gives me the base `index.js`, going to `/blog` gives me `blog/index.js`, and going to `/blog/my-post` gives me `blog/[slug].js` — so far so good.

But going to `/blog/` gives me a 404 error, and there appears to be no way at all to handle this without entirely replacing the next.js router—I can't even redirect `/blog/` to `/blog`. Is there any way around this, or do I need a custom router? Is there a way to extend the next.js router in a way that will let me handle these, without entirely replacing it?

Comment: what do you mean with `next.js router`. it's not clear to me

Comment: Basically, I mean needing to write a function somewhere to handle routing (e.g. in a `server.js` file), instead of just leaning next.js's native routing that relies on the directory structure of `/pages`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE: If you are using `next export` than you can solve the issue by adding `exportTrailingSlash` to your `next.config.js`

As of this writing, there seems to be no way to solve this issue without defining your own custom server.

Previous answer:

You must create a new file `blog.js` shown bellow:

[image]

With the following server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express()

    server.get('/blog', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/blog'
     // const queryParams = { title: req.params.id }
      app.render(req, res, '/blog', {})
    })
    server.get('/blog/:id', (req, res) => {
      const actualPage = '/blog/[id]'
      const queryParams = { title: req.params.id }
      app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
    })

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res)
    })

    server.listen(PORT, err => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    })
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

`node server.js` should start your server and you would have the mapping that you need.

Note, `blog/index.js` is not used in this example.

Comment: Also this issue is an [open issue on next.js issues](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5214)

Comment: tnxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx , you saved my life <3

Answer (score 12):

There is an option with `Next.js 9.5` and up.

In `next.config.js`, add the `trailingSlash` config:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Source: **[Trailing Slash](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash)**

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution to this. This is still a massive problem. However, I do have a very horrible hack that I've been using to workaround this problem in Next.js 9.x.x

In my `/pages/_error.js` I've added the following code:

```js
FourOhFour.getInitialProps = ({asPath, res}: any): any => {
    if (asPath.endsWith('/')) {
        res.writeHead(301, {Location: asPath.substring(0, asPath.length - 1)});
        return res.end();
    }

    return {};
};
```

This will ensure that all routes that end with a trailing slash are redirected to the non-trailing slash path via a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `_app.js` file

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  const pathAndQueryDivided = ctx.ctx.req.url.split('?');
  if (pathAndQueryDivided[0].endsWith('/')) {
    const urlWithoutEndingSlash = pathAndQueryDivided[0].replace(/\/*$/gim, '');

    ctx.ctx.res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: urlWithoutEndingSlash + (pathAndQueryDivided.length > 1 ? `?${pathAndQueryDivided[1]}` : ''),
    });
    ctx.ctx.res.end();
    return {};
  }
    

  const initialProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
      ...initialProps,
  };
};
```

- App.getInitialProps gets called first server-side
- It divides splits the path and the query params because we only want to know if the url ends with a slash
- It asks if the url ends with a slash
- It replaces the last slash of the url with nothing
- It redirects you to the url without the slash + the query params if there's any

Comment: Do not do this.  It will causes your entire app to require an SSR function and will stop static optimization on all pages that don't require SSR.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve done that redirect by using nginx for my production app:

```
rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;
```