# NextJS: trailing slash show Forbidden error msg

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I deployed a NextJS app to the server (non-vercel). In NextJS, is there a different between the 2 URL below?:

1. https://benderaputih.icu/cuisines
2. https://benderaputih.icu/cuisines/

The URL without the trailing slash has no problem.
But,the URL with the trailing slash show following error:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Can someone shed a light?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How can you handle trailing slashes in next.js routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476602/1870780)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
Open next.config.js and add the trailingSlash config:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

With this option set, urls like /about will redirect to /about/.

Ref : https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash